# Personal pronoun with a gerund or infinitive?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

My father never approved _____ a foreigner.

> a. her to marry
>    b. her marrying
>    c. she marrying
>    d. she not marry

Please answer the question with an explanation.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No Sir, It is competitive exam's previous year question.

Comment: It's complicated because in addition to the variants here, you can have "approved her marrying" and "approved of her marrying", etc, with slightly different meanings: "approved of" suggests a more general attitude while "approved" suggests an explicit giving of approval.

Answer (score 0):

Either a or b work grammatically, but **b** is the most idiomatic and seems correct:

> My father never approved her marrying a foreigner.

"Her marrying" is the action of her getting married. It is this that the father did not approve of.

Although "My father never approved *her to marry* a foreigner" makes grammatical sense, it sounds like the father had to give some kind of formal approval for his daughter to marry a foreigner, which is clearly not the case if she married a foreigner anyway.

To be really fussy, I would prefer if it said "my father never approved **of** her marrying a foreigner", but evidently that is not an option for you.